# How can I set a specific background to a random quote?

Tags: javascript

So, I have my quotes in one array, and I have my background images in another. My background images are in the order of which quote it belongs to. I am wondering how can I make it to when a certain quote shows up randomly, then the background image for that quote shows too? Please and thank you! This is all in my Javascript file by the way.

This is what my JavaScript looks like (my quotes and background images are above this):

```js
function newQuote(){
 
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
 document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
newQuote();

$("#button").on("click",function(){
 
newQuote();
 
});
```

Comment: You would probably set the background to `images[randomNumber]` too. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried that too. People have suggested to create a variable called index and then it took a random number and they set quote = quote[index]. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function newQuote(){
       var quotes = ["quote1","quote2","quote3"];
       var bg_image_url = ["image1.com","image2.com","image3.com"];

   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
        document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
            document.body.style.backgroundImage  =  "url('"+bg_image_url[randomNumber]+"')";
    }
    newQuote();

    $("#button").on("click",function(){

    newQuote();

    });
```

Comment: let me know if you have any concern

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: Does it make a difference if my images are from online and end in jpg, png or any others?

Comment: it does not matter. The source(.png, .jpg, online) can be anything you want as long as it is valid image

Comment: Oh my goodness!! Thank you so much!!! It works!! I have to resize my images other than that, it works perfectly!! I appreciate your help and I appreciate everyone else who replied to this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below.

```
function newQuote(){

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
    var color= color[randomNumber];
    document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
newQuote();

$("#button").on("click",function(){

newQuote();

});
```

Comment: Can I change backgroundColor to backgroundImage?

Comment: `var color= color[randomNumber];` oops.

Comment: Yes you can specify backgroundImage as you mentioned.